# StackOverflowError when running H2 unit test in NetBeans

Tags: java, database, unit-testing, junit, h2

When I run or debug a unit test within NetBeans which uses the H2 database I get a StackOverflowError:

...

```
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass(Launcher.java:229)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:295)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:230)
    at org.h2.command.CommandList.update(CommandList.java:44)
    at org.h2.command.CommandList.executeRemaining(CommandList.java:39)
    at org.h2.command.CommandList.update(CommandList.java:45)
    at org.h2.command.CommandList.executeRemaining(CommandList.java:39)
    at org.h2.command.CommandList.update(CommandList.java:45)
    at org.h2.command.CommandList.executeRemaining(CommandList.java:39)
    at org.h2.command.CommandList.update(CommandList.java:45)
    at org.h2.command.CommandList.executeRemaining(CommandList.java:39)
    at org.h2.command.CommandList.update(CommandList.java:45)
    at org.h2.command.CommandList.executeRemaining(CommandList.java:39)
    at org.h2.command.CommandList.update(CommandList.java:45)
    at org.h2.command.CommandList.executeRemaining(CommandList.java:39)
    at org.h2.command.CommandList.update(CommandList.java:45)
    at org.h2.command.CommandList.executeRemaining(CommandList.java:39)
```

... etc

When I run the complete set of unit test from ant I have no problem. Also running the single unit test from IntelliJ works fine.

Help is appreciated. Please refrain from answers like "switch to IntelliJ", I'd like to keep using my favorite IDE.

Comment: Any chance you use two different VMs to run your tests in NetBeans, command line and IntelliJ IDE?

Comment: Hm, do you know what SQL statement this is? Maybe it's a very very long one. To find out, you could append `;TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=3` to the database URL and see in the `dbName.trace.db` file.

Comment: It is a long statement, but why is that a problem within NetBeans?

Comment: Maybe because the default stack size is smaller in NetBeans. How long is the statement exactly (in characters, and in number of sub-statements)?

Answer (score 2):

Solved by increasing the stack size of the JVM. In the File->Project properties->Run I set the VM Options with -Xss to a bigger value.